# add value to a particular list in nested list C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to add a value to specific list from nested list. It will if there is any list contains a value called inputString, if yes, then add result into this list; if no, then create new list with result. The codes are as follows.

```
           foreach(List<string> List in returnList )
            {
                    if (List.Contains(inputString))
                    {
                        //add a string called 'result' to this List
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        returnList.Add(new List<string> {result});

                    }
            }
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: `List.Add(result);` ??

Comment: Just call `List.add(result)`?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is in your else branch:

```
foreach (List<string> List in returnList)
{
    if (List.Contains(inputString))
    {
        //add a string called 'result' to this List
        List.Add(result);    // no problem here
    }
    else
    {
        // but this blows up the foreach
        returnList.Add(new List<string> { result });  
    }
}
```

The solution isn't hard,

```
// make a copy with ToList() for the foreach()
foreach (List<string> List in returnList.ToList())  
{
   // everything the same
}
```